# Log File (Crash information) - iOS Application (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, logging, crash

I want to save a log file of my iOS application. I found different way here on stack overflow, but I'm not interested in saving only what I print (this is pretty simple), but also all the automatic log by the application.
For example if the app crash for a nil reference I want that also this information (that appear in the console if you are running the app on Xcode) would be appended to the file.
How can I do?
Thanks

PS: I'm working with Swift 4